# Touch typing tutor with attention to programming keys

Tags: windows, educational

I'm looking for a typing tutor that *also* gives enough attention to all the keys that a programmer often requires: the function keys, brackets, backslash etc that are all on the 'edges' of the keyboard.
Also: it really helps having to practice combinations like <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (pinky on right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?) and <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> (pinky on left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?)

Some earlier questions on the site do not address that:
[Touch-typing tutor for Windows XP?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/touch-typing-tutor-for-windows-xp)
[What is the most effective free software to train typing speed on Windows 10 for a user that types 55 WPM?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37933/what-is-the-most-effective-free-software-to-train-typing-speed-on-windows-10-for)

Either Windows or online; preferably free.

I'm not interested in speed training per se, for me it's just to pull my eyes away from the keyboard as one measure to resolve upper back issues.
No need for fancy features like statistics, audio, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not a complete touch typing tutor, I think [typing.io](https://typing.io) is worth a look.

From the website:

> - Practice typing the awkward characters in code.
> - No drills — type through open source code in JavaScript, Ruby, C, C++, Java, PHP, Perl, Haskell, Scala, and more.
> - Eliminate the mistyped keys delaying every edit-compile-test iteration.

[image: typing.io's JavaScript (jQuery) first lesson]

You can choose one of 16 programming languages to practice, and each language's lessons are based on source code from a well-known open source project in that language. Also, the lessons usually contain tricky symbol sequences similar to what you might have type in the language that you're practicing.

The *Touch Typing Fingering Guide* is a paid feature, but the available lessons are free if you sign in with a Google account.

Comment: The only thing this site seems to miss is actual 'artificial' exercises to emphasize training those awkward key combinations, you can only do that with code examples. And $10/month is a bit steep, so I will use one of the 'regular' typing tutors first before I start using this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your typing is like mine. Fine with the 26 alphabetic keys and then progressively worse as I start to use numbers and then symbols.

**Typingclub.com**

https://www.typingclub.com/

**Pros**

very generous free tier
lots of exercises
eg group of symbol exercises so you can focus on your areas of weaknesses
https://www.typingclub.com/sportal/program-86/20193.play eg lesson 412
Option for UK keyboard set of exercises

**Cons**

no programming specific content eg javascript code

**Speedcoder.net**

https://www.speedcoder.net

eg practice on some php or javascript (is the % tough keys high enough?)
only 5 exercies per language in free tier

**Cons**

Typing interface not as slick

**Others**

https://typing.io/

https://www.keybr.com/
Just started to use this.
I seem to be stuck on the letter u key, i.e. cannot progress to more keys
not sure why.

**Monkeytype.com**

https://monkeytype.com/
Pros
visually great design, lacking user guide
Code Javascript etc

https://monkeytype.com/settings/code javascript

**Cons**
No user guide